# Cant load Prelude in ghci interpreter in VS code

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, ghci, haskell-prelude

I have installed Haskell platform following the instructions on chocolatey and haskell.org.
I am using Windows 10.
My hello.hs program complies in command prompt, but when I try to do the same in VS code,
it won't load Prelude, which I assume is necessary for running Haskell programs.
I think it might be a configuration problem, but I cant find any useful documentation on it.
How could I fix this and turn on Prelude?
Are the problems that VS code shows relevant to this problem?

[image: Pewlude not showing up]
[image: Problems in VS code]

Comment: By "it won't load Prelude", do you mean that the prompt shows `ghci>` instead of `Prelude>`? If so, that is not a problem; the difference is just in appearance.

Comment: That's right, but how do I run the program then? In all instructions that I saw so far, you just need to type ghci, and then it should switch to Prelude> automatically, which doesnt happen in my case. I tried running the way it is now, but it woulnt work

Comment: Try `ghci hello.hs"` when you start `ghci`, or `:l hello.hs` at the `ghci>` prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing looks wrong in your screenshots. The prompt text is `ghci>`  rather than `Prelude>`   because GHCi no longer defaults to showing the loaded modules on the prompt (see [the GHC 9.0.1 changelog](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/9.0.1-notes.html#ghci). `Prelude` is being loaded regardless. The warning shown in the IDE is a style suggestion that is inconsequential for the purpose of getting your code to run. [As chi suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620196/cant-load-prelude-in-ghci-interpreter-in-vs-code#comment117771492_66620196), `:l hello.hs` at the GHCi prompt should be enough to have it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If I type main into the console, then it works

```
ghci> main
"haskell"
 name
 "hi, name"
 ghci>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work

```sh
$ ghci
ghci> import Prelude
Prelude> printStrLn "Hello World!"
Hello World!
Prelude>
```

You may need to just run `import Prelude`.

Comment: @DLaningham I am not familiar with Windows, could it be that the VSCode terminal is using a different terminal application than what you installed GHC on?

Comment: (1) It is highly unlikely that the Prelude is actually not being loaded at the OP's prompt; all signs point to a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). (2) Even if the Prelude weren't being loaded, `import Prelude` wouldn't change the prompt text from `ghci> ` (a fixed string)  to `Prelude> ` (the list of loaded modules). (3) You meant `putStrLn` rather than `printStrLn` (I know it's just a typo, but it is a confusing one for someone completely new to the language like the OP).